# Laravel store nested json

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm pretty new to Laravel, and I try to make a simple API where I make a POST with a nested JSON in the body, and it should save to the DB, and update (upsert) (I can use PUT, but that's not the point)

also, I want to keep the ID of everything on every table, so I need to update the references.

ultimately I want each model to store itself, what would be a good structure to write this?

(of course I have a controller and relationship setup)

```json
  "templates_id": 7,
  "pages": [
    {
      "pages_id": 7,
      "templates_id": 7,
      "components": [
        {
          "components_id": 167,
          "templates_id": 7,
          "pages_id": 8,
          "lines": [
            {
              "lines_id": 120,
              "components_id": 167,
              "templates_id": 7
            },
            {
              "lines_id": 121,
              "components_id": 167,
              "templates_id": 7
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

code I currently wrote:

```php
<?php
class Template extends Model {
    protected $table = 'templates';
    protected $primaryKey = 'templates_id';
    protected $guarded = [];

    function addComponents($data)
    {

        $this->pages()->createMany($data);
        $this->pages->each(function (TemplatesPage $page, $pageIndex) use ($data) {
            $page->components()->createMany($this->filterOutNestedObjects($data[$pageIndex]['components']));
            $page->refresh();
            $page->components->each(function (TemplatesComponent $component, $componentIndex) use ($page, $data, $pageIndex) {
                $component->lines()->createMany($data[$pageIndex]['components'][$componentIndex]['lines']);

                //        add association with template
                $component->template()->associate($this);
                $component->save();
                $component->refresh();

                $component->lines->each(function (TemplatesComponentsLine $componentLine, $componentIndex) use ($page, $data, $pageIndex) {

                    //        add association with template
                    $componentLine->template()->associate($this);
                    $componentLine->page()->associate($page);
                    $componentLine->save();
                });
            });
        });
    }

    public function updateComponents($data)
    {
        $this->pages()->upsert($this->filterOutNestedObjects($data), ['templates_id', 'pages_id']);
        $this->pages->each(function (TemplatesPage $page, $pageIndex) use ($data) {
            $page->components()->upsert($data[$pageIndex]['components']);
            $page->refresh();
            $page->components->each(function (TemplatesComponent $component, $componentIndex) use ($page, $data, $pageIndex) {

                $component->lines()->upsert($data[$pageIndex]['components'][$componentIndex]['lines'],);

                $component->save();
                $component->refresh();

            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's [Resource collection classes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources). In combination you could also use [Query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes) so you don't have to repeat yourself any time, and you should use controllers to combine everything together to save the actual data.

Comment: can I use Resource collection for storing? if yes how?

Comment: https://medium.com/@moinuddinchowdhury/a-complete-laravel-crud-using-laravel-resource-api-with-vue-js-69ff0bc367d4 

So what you actual do is just return the resource with the object you just saved.

Comment: i know that, my problem is the saving part